# Making a UIImage in UITableViewCell look recessed

Tags: ios, photoshop

This is sort of a photoshop question, I suppose, but does anybody know how to make a nice looking heart that's recessed? Sort of like this one, except recessed:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic letterpress effect can be achieved by having a white (or light coloured) drop shadow 1 point below the image. This is what is used in iOS for the status bar images and text, for example.

You may also want an inner shadow inside the top edge, and possibly a subtle gradient (<strike>lighter</strike>darker at the top - note I have changed my mind on the gradient, but not updated the image!) instead of a solid background colour.

Here's a 5 minute bodge job done in Pixelmator. The inner shadow at the top is particularly amateurish, but I prefer drawing things like this in code!

[image]

Comment: Is there an example you could give? My photoshop skills are absolutely terrible. If not, that's alright

Comment: I don't even have photoshop, so you probably beat me! I'm answering on the phone at the moment but I'll try to whip something up later if I can.

Comment: That would be so awesome. And yea I got photoshop free by a university, haha.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few layer styles which can compliment each other to give you that recessed look.

1. A light *drop* shadow beneath the sprite (1px white shadow directly below usually does the trick, but you can experiment with its softness/size)
2. A gradient which is darker at the top and lighter near the bottom
3. A dark *inner* shadow which is at the top of the sprite. (1px black, for example)

If you're doing this in Photoshop, make sure to have the light angle set to 90º

Comment: I disagree with you about the direction of the gradient, but +1 for the light angle - all iOS light should be coming from directly above.

Comment: I've changed my mind, you're right about the gradient. Have a (virtual) +1 on top of the real one.